# Future[List[Error \/ Double]] to Future[[List[Error] \/ List[Double]] in Scala

Tags: list, scala, scalaz, either

I'm playing around with Scala(z) to learn functionnal programming.

I have a value of type `Future[List[Error \/ Double]]` and want to transform it to something with the type `Future[[List[Error] \/ List[Double]]`.

The goal is to group the lefts and rights.

I currently have the following:

```
val foo: Future[List[Error] \/ List[Double]] = {
  for {
    results <- resultsF
  } yield
    results.foldLeft(\/[List[Error], List[Double]])({
      case (acc, v) if v.isRight => v :: \/-(acc)
      case (acc, v) if v.isLeft => v :: -\/(acc)
    })
}
```

However, I get an error on the `::` which is due to the fact that my accumulator is not a list (from the outside) `\/[List[Error], List[Double]]`. How should it be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This function in Haskell would be `partitionEithers`: `[Either a b] -> ([a], [b])`.

(You don't actually want `Either [a] [b]`, that wouldn't really make sense. I'm guessing you want this function instead because of the text in your description...)

Scalaz doesn't have it as-is. However, it has a more general [`separate`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/ea856759e60d0d3fbf2becc7b4e1918ecdf70085/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/MonadPlus.scala#L24):

```
/** Generalized version of Haskell's `partitionEithers` */
def separate[G[_, _], A, B](value: F[G[A, B]])(implicit G: Bifoldable[G]): (F[A], F[B])
```

Which is basically `Bifoldable g, MonadPlus f => f (g a b) -> (f a), (f b)`. Specifically: `[Either a b] -> ([a], [b])`.
You can simply call it on your list (where `g = \/` (or Either), `f = List`).

In action:

```
scala> import scalaz._, Scalaz._
scala> List(\/-(3), -\/("a")).separate
res1: (List[String], List[Int]) = (List(a),List(3))
```

Comment: After you've imported `scalaz.Scalaz._`.

Comment: @EndeNeu right, hehe... That's in my sbtrc file... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Strictly, you can implement such function, for example, how do you apply this list:

```
-\/(A) :: \/-(B) :: Nil
```

Assume the input list is all left or all right, you can peek the first one , and decide how to deal the remains:

```
val foo: Future[List[Error] \/ List[Double]] =
  resultsF.map(resultsF.head match {
    case -\/(_) => { _.left }
    case \/-(_) => { _.right }
  })
```

Assume you want to group lefts and rights, a single fold which returns (List[L], List[R]) works perfectly:

```
val foo[L,R]: Future[(List[L], List[R])] =
  resultsF.foldr((Nil, Nil)){ (s, v) =>
    case -\/(l) => (l :: s._1, s._2)
    case \/-(r) => (s._1, r :: s._2)
  }
```

Comment: Yes, the type in the question is incorrect. Cf "The goal is to group the lefts and rights." which gives the hint as to what the op's looking for.